# Adding links on images

Tags: pages

I can't find a way to add links on my images, am I missing something? I tried via the menu but the option seems locked or with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> but this has no effect either.

Any clue on what's going on? If it's not possible, is there a known hack for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pages... It's grayed out because you do not have any text selected to become the link.

To place a link on a image, after you have added it to the page, insert a text box.

In the text box, type what you want to be the link, select it and press **⌘K** to add the URL to the link.

Resize and reposition the text box over the image where you want it.

---

Here is an image with a link on it and clicked:

[image: HAL 9000]

Comment: It can only be attributable to human error. I imagine the Pages team still thinks it's 2001 and links on images are overrated. Odd. Anyway, thanks for the hacky workaround.